# React JS: 'Message' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a learner and beginner to React JS i am making a messaging web app. when i wrote my code it show an error that :

```
Failed to compile.
```

./src/App.js
Line 41:17:  'Message' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

here is my code:

```
 {
        messages.map(message => ( <
            Message username = { message.username }
            text = { message.text }
            />
        ))
    }
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Are you having any component with `<Message />` name?

Comment: Seems you are not importing your Message component

Comment: yeah! thanks for your comment I imported and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have are using Message component from React js, for that you can make a separate java script file with name 'Message.js' with function name message as follows:

```
    import React from 'react'

function Message(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.text}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Message
```

In your working file you need to import Message by using:

```
import Message from './Message';
```

Now your code will run, make sure you are using proper syntax and cases for null error. Thank you!